# how to solve Azure synapse scala notebook error TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled?

Tags: scala, azure-synapse, azure-notebooks

I have below synpase pipeline which has 4 notebook activities. i am using large spark pool. second notebook throw error TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. can anyone help me with this?

Notebook Code :-

```
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("y-MM-dd") //Store current date
println(format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()))


if (metadata_df.count() > 0){
for (row <- metadata_df.rdd.collect){
    val a = row(0)
    println(a)
    val Input_Path = f"abfss://$container_name@$account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/$relative_path/"+ format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + "/"+a+"/*"
    var DF = spark.read.option("mergeSchema",true).format("parquet").load(Input_Path)
    //display(DF)
    //val column_list = DF.columns
    //val DF1 = DF.select(column_list.map(name => func(col(name))): _*).drop("LastModifytime")
    val DF1 = DF.drop("LastModifytime")
    val Out_Path = f"abfss://$container_name@$account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/Staging/"+a+"/HotData/"
    DF1.repartition(1).write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(Out_Path);
    }
  }
```

pipeline snapshot:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SII92.png)

configure

```
%%configure session -f
{
    // You can get a list of valid parameters to config the session from https://github.com/cloudera/livy#request-body.
    "driverMemory": "112g", // Recommended values: ["28g", "56g", "112g", "224g", "400g", "472g"]
    "driverCores": 16, // Recommended values: [4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 80]
    "executorMemory": "112g",
    "executorCores": 16,
    //"jars": ["abfs[s]: //<file_system>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/myjar.jar", "wasb[s]: //<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>/myjar1.jar"],
    "conf":
    {
        // Example of standard spark property, to find more available properties please visit: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties.
        "spark.driver.maxResultSize": "64g",
        // Example of customized property, you can specify count of lines that Spark SQL returns by configuring "livy.rsc.sql.num-rows".
        "livy.rsc.sql.num-rows": "300000",
        "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval":10
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to share more details about the failing Notebook. I've seen similar problems when a C# cell encounters an unhandled Exception.

Comment: code updated..!! how i can removed executors by code or shutdown spark session before it failed.